# Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified - Ubuntu production server

Tags: .net, api, ubuntu, certificate

I've been running a .NET6 API on Ubuntu 20.04 with NGINX, hosted in AWS EC2, since about March 2022.  Today we did a routine deployment and the service running the API would not come back up.  First time this has ever happened.

Output from `systemctl restart` followed by `systemctl status`:

```
Anovite.Api.service - .NET Web API App running on Ubuntu
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/Anovite.Api.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: core-dump) since Sun 2023-01-08 22:18:31 UTC; 8s ago
    Process: 1970 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/Anovite.Api/Anovite.Api.dll (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
   Main PID: 1970 (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
```

I ran command journalctl -f and got the following output:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of dat
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Reload()
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.Load()
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.Run(String url)
```

At first I was concerned that our certificates had expired.  They were created using letsencrypt.  When I went to request a new certificate it alerted me that the existing certificate is nowhere near expiring.

Googling the error messages shown above leads me to numerous threads where a dev machine is being affected.  In my case this is not a dev machine.  We are not attempting to launch the API and browse it on the same machine.  This is a production server.  I'm confused why the .NET runtime all of a sudden thinks it needs a dev cert when we have valid, unexpired certificates already installed.

The default.conf file for NGINX specifies the path to the directory where the certificate is saved on the host.  The config file has not been edited in months.

.NET versions currently running:

```
dotnet --list-sdks
6.0.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

The strangest thing of all is that rolling back to the previous version of the API had no effect resolving this problem.  The problem started after the new version's files were copied up and the API service restarted.  After reverting to the backup of the previous files the API service still would not restart.  We're getting 503 Bad Gateway on Postman requests to the API regardless of which version we deploy.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

FIXED, but with some new concerns...

I ran this command and got the subsequent output

```
dotnet dev-certs https
The HTTPS developer certificate was generated successfully.
```

Immediately following that, I restarted the API service using `systemctl restart`.  The API began responding normally again.

I'm concerned that renewing a dev certificate was necessary to fix a problem in production.  During the initial release of this environment, letsencrypt was used to create and store certificates on the host, then they are explicitly pathed in the NGINX config file (actual domain is removed in what's pasted here):

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name <domain>.com;
        return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
        ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM;
        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
        resolver_timeout 5s;
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

        server_name <domain>.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5164;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                #proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For
                $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        }
}
```

The above config has worked well for us.  NGINX reverse proxies to Kestrel server, so all HTTPS requests terminate at NGINX and are then forwarded to the specified port for Kestrel and .NET to respond.  Maybe I'm showing my ignorance here, but I was under the impression that the letsencrypt certs specified in this config were being used and NOT some dev cert generated by the .NET SDK or runtime???

Created these certs with letsencrypt actually resulted in browser security warnings going away.  So I'm confident they are being used but I'm totally baffled by the need for a renewed dev cert.

Please someone illuminate me.